# How to display a set of combined posts and pages using Wordpress' query_posts() method

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I've got a template that I'm using that has the option of showing either a set of posts on the front page in a featured section or, optionally, display a set of specified pages in the same featured area.  I found the code where it displays either/or, however **I'm not exactly sure how to combine the two together and get a list of a set of posts AND pages together.**

It's my understanding that query_posts() overrides whatever set of items Wordpress displays on the page, so here, depending on what mode the theme is in, it passes in parameters to query_posts() to grab posts of a particular category, or passes in an array of pages:

```
<div id="slides">
    <?php global $ids;
    $ids = array(); 

    $featured_cat = get_option('mytemplate_feat_cat'); 
    $featured_num = get_option('mytemplate_featured_num'); 

    if (get_option('mytemplate_use_pages') == 'false') query_posts("showposts=$featured_num&cat=".get_cat_ID($featured_cat));
    else {
        global $pages_number;

        if (get_option('mytemplate_feat_pages') <> '') $featured_num = count(get_option('mytemplate_feat_pages'));
        else $featured_num = $pages_number;

        query_posts(array
                        ('post_type' => 'page',
                        'orderby' => 'menu_order',
                        'order' => 'ASC',
                        'post__in' => get_option('mytemplate_feat_pages'),
                        'showposts' => $featured_num
                    ));
    } ?>
            <!-- Start my loop to display everything-->
    <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();
    global $post; ?>
```

So far, I've made it a little more consise, but can't get over the last little bit of how to combine the parameters to say query_posts(getMyPostsArray().AddList(ohINeedACouplePagesToo())) //Yes, I know this looks like C# or something...I'm not a PHP guy..

here's the code in a little more readable version that's closer to what I want:

```
            $featured_cat = get_option('mytemplate_feat_cat'); 
                //I combined featured_num to get the total number of featured items to display
        $featured_num = get_option('mytemplate_featured_num') + count(get_option('mytemplate_feat_pages'));; 

query_posts("showposts=$featured_num&cat=".get_cat_ID($featured_cat));

            //I think this second line overwrites the first query_posts() :-/
            query_posts(array
                            ('post_type' => 'page',
                            'orderby' => 'menu_order',
                            'order' => 'ASC',
                            'post__in' => get_option('mytemplate_feat_pages'),
                            'showposts' => $featured_num
                        ));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ryan, why don't you just go ahead with two queries and two loops?

```
query_posts("post_type=post&showposts=3");
while (have_posts()) { the_post(); }

query_posts(array(
    "post_type" => "page",
    "post__in" => get_option("mytemplate_feat_pages"),
    "showposts" => 5
));
while (have_posts()) { the_post(); }
```

If you need a certain number of posts and pages to fill in the space, you can also use `$wp_query->found_posts` to actually calculate what you have and what you need. This would probably be the easiest solution, since even if you can get posts and pages in SQL, you might have a hard time ordering them, since posts don't have a menu order, while you wouldn't like pages ordered by publish date.

Hope that helped,
Cheers!

Comment: Running it twice worked like a charm.  For some reason I was thinking query_posts could only be run once per page.  I just ran it twice, once for posts and then pages.  Thanks!